# Git includeIf GIT_AUTHOR_NAME set to my name

Tags: git, config

I'm working on a joint account with some other users, but would like to use my own .gitconfig. I use SendEnv with SSH to send GIT_AUTHOR_NAME among other things and my idea is that I would like to use this to only source my gitconfig if my name is contained in that variable.

What I've tried so far is to use [includeIf](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.27.0#_conditional_includes)

```
[includeIf "hasconfig:author.name:My Name"]
    path = ~/my_name/.gitconfig
```

however, either hasconfig isn't available in git 2.27.0 (which is the version I'm using) or this fails because of another reason.

There is also to possibility of using

```bash
if [[ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" == "My Name" ]]; then
    . ~/my_name/.bashrc
fi
```

in the joint .bashrc and then taking care of it in my .bashrc.

But using `GIT_CONFIG` environment variable seem to only work with the `git config` command. If that still worked for all commands it would have been the best solution for me.

I have seen a suggestion of creating an alias

```bash
alias git="HOME=~/my_name command git"
```

and that is the best one I've seen so far, but I don't like that solution particularly much.

Is it possible to query environment variables in an includeIf expression? Or is there some other approach to include if GIT_AUTHOR_NAME is set to a specific variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `hasconfig` was in fact new in Git 2.36.0 (see [the release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9c32cfb49c60fa8173b9666db02efe3b45a8522f/Documentation/RelNotes/2.36.0.txt#L127-L130)).  Second, `includeIf.hasconfig:remote.*.url:...`  only works for remote URLs (see the same release notes and the accompanying updated documentation).  This means even if you update your Git version, you won't be able to test `author.name` here.

> Is it possible to query environment variables in an includeIf expression?

Not in general, no.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than have Git do logic on the environment, just set it up as you like. You can set the `$HOME` and `$XDG_*` vars to your customized-to-you-personally environment and everything will Just Work. Start with `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, put `git/config` there and it's your personal git config. [XDG vars](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=xdg+environment+variables).